# Гуттаперчевый, гуталин — этимология

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Можно ли отнести слова "гуттаперчевый" и "гуталин" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Даже слово *орангутан* не является этимологически однокоренным со словом *гуттаперчевый*, хотя оба происходят из малайского языка.

Вот ещё некоторые слова, содержащие буквосочетание **гут** (наличие этих букв в слове не обязательно говорит об их этимологическом родстве):

> агути; безжгутиковый; гернгутеры; гуммигут; гута; гутарить; гутный; гуторить; гуттаперча; гуттаперчевый; гуттация; гуттуральный; гутты; жгут; жгутик; жгутиковые; жгутиконосцы; жгутовый; жгутоногие; загутарить; загутариться; кетгут; кетгутный; кремнежгутиковые; могутный; орангутан; орангутанг; погутарить; погуторить; разножгутиковый; сургутец; сургутский; сургутянин; штейнгут; эгутёр.